# How do I create a grid system using handlebars in Meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I'm trying to build a simple memory card game in Meteor and I can't seem to create a grid of my cards to populate in html.  I'm just trying to get a 4x4 grid for right now.

Here is the javascript:

```js
Template.body.helpers({
    cards: function() {
      var allCards = Deck.find({}).fetch();
      var chunks = [];

      while (allCards.length > 0) {
        chunks.push(allCards.slice(0, 4));
        allCards = allCards.slice(4);
      }

      return chunks;
    },
  });
```

And here is the HTML:

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div name="gameBoard">
      {{#each cards}}
        {{> cardsRow}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

<template name="cardsRow">
  <div class="row">
    {{#each row}}
      {{> card}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="card">
  <span class="text">{{text}}</span>
</template>
```

Right now I just have simple text entries in the db to see what I'm doing before I pull in images.  I've tried console logging from my JS and I believe I'm creating the array of spliced rows correctly so I think the problem may be in the way I have arranged the markdown.

I tried pulling the each cards loop into a template as well instead of inside the body but I'm not sure how to render templates on demand.  This is potentially an option since I have a new game button event listener that could call a render.  I'm just not sure how to explicitly render in Meteor.

I tried following this previous post but I couldn't get it to work: 
[How do I populate a bootstrap grid system using handlebars for each command in Meteor.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674346/how-do-i-populate-a-bootstrap-grid-system-using-handlebars-for-each-command-in-m)

Thoughts?  I can provide more of my code base if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `row` in `{{#each row}}` in the "cardsRow" template, nor `{{text}}` in the "cards" template, refer the way that you hope they do. You need to define `row` and `text` as template helpers for each of these templates. In a template helper, `this` refers to the data object associated with the template.

In your case, when you iterate through `#each cards` in "container", `this` is passed into the "cardsRow" template as one of the `chunks` defined in your `cards` helper function. The helpers below should illustrate this, and are sufficient for your example.

```
Template.cardsRow.helpers({
    row: function() {
        console.log(this); // a chunk of cards
        return this;
    }
});

Template.card.helpers({
    text: function() {
        console.log(this); // a number in a chunk
        return this;
    }
});
```

Comment: With such a simple example, you could refer to `this` directly in your template, just FYI: `<span class="text">{{this}}</span>`

Comment: Thanks! I got it working now.  Yeah I think I was confusing the {{text}} inside the html file as referencing the database but really its what is returned from the helper method in the js file.  I just called this.text in the return and I can see my sample characters.