# Create table for Result of MongoDB Query

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am fetching a list of items from MongoDB and it displays one item per line.

But i want to display x (e.g. 3) items per Line instead of just 1. How can i achieve this? Shall i use a table?

**Current output with unordered list:**

-item1
-item2
-item3
-...

**Achieved output:**

item1 item2 item3

item4 item5 item6

item7 item8 item9

Comment: Already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18681564/2805154

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I populate a bootstrap grid system using handlebars for each command in Meteor.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674346/how-do-i-populate-a-bootstrap-grid-system-using-handlebars-for-each-command-in-m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i thought to complicated on this topic and didn't consider, that divs can solve my task:

- one div-container (about 610px, let's name it deviceWrapper)
- x child divs (name: device) --> so 2 devices per line are organised

```css
#deviceWrapper{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 610px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 5px;
}

.device{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, assuming you have a table in your markup:

```
$.each(yourListOfItems, function(index, value){

    var tRow = $('<tr>');

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
        var tCell = $('<td>');
        tCell.text(value);
        tRow.append(tCell)
    }

    $(#yourTableID).append(tRow)
});
```